# Multiple javascript functions on one input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to use 2 functions on one input field. But only the tagsinput works.

Function 1 = Bootstrap tagsinput

Function 2 = jquery autocomplete

Sources:
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Tried applying the autocomplete on `.autotest` instead of `#tagsearch` but that doesn't do anything either.

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tagsearch" class="autotest" id="tagsearch" value="" placeholder="Zoek op functie">
```

JS code:

```
//Var to set for maximum tags we allow
$iMaximumTags = 5;

//Maximum of 5 tags
$('#tagsearch').tagsinput({
    maxTags: $iMaximumTags,
    trimValue: true
});

    //Autocomplete test
var countries = [
   { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
   // ...
   { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#tagsearch').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

When I remove the tags input code the autocomplete works.
There are no JS errors.

If the autocomplete code is above the tags input, still only the tags input works.

Comment: can't you use `onchange`?

Comment: The answer you need is [here](https://phppot.com/jquery/tags-using-bootstrap-tags-input-plugin-with-autocomplete/), no need to keep this question.

Comment: why not call a javascript function like this onselect=yourFucntion(); And ofcourse you can create one function from 2 or make a call to a function from another function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serching for id (#tagsearch) change:( $('#tagsearch').autocomplete({ and $('#tagsearch').tagsinput({ )with( $('.text').autocomplete({ and $('.text').tagsinput({
it should works.